# AngularJS : Transclude a single input element into a directive template without using a container

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, transclusion

I would like to create a wrapper for my input field with an input-help tool tip inside of it.

I am using angular 1.0.7, if it's significant.

I'm using transclude: true, along with isolate scope in order to allow errors  at several different fields simultaneously, and still maintain the ng-model reference to the external $scope.

**The Problem**:

when I use this directive on the input element, the input element doesn't clone('Transclude') into the directive template.

As a result of that I am getting an empty div element at the DOM, with an ng-transclude attribute.

plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/vFB9ih6x2NBmwhAes3Qh?p=preview

code:

```
<input data-my-validate-input data-value-required="true" type="password" class="loginItem" placeholder="Password" name="password" data-ng-model="formData.password" data-display-name="Password">
```

However  when I wrap this input element in a span or div, the child input element is transcended just fine, but then I don't get the a reference to the correct external ng-model(ctrl) at the directive.

```
<span data-my-validate-input data-value-required="true" data-display-name="Password">
      <input type="password" class="loginItem" placeholder="Password" name="password" data-ng-model="formData.password" >    
</span>
```

Full code(the logic inside the link function is not relevant to the problem, but I preferred to post my full code)

```
directive('myValidateInput', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
          restrict: 'A',
          transclude: true,
          scope: {
            displayName: '@',
            valueRequired: '@',
            maxLength: '@',
            minLength: '@',
            minLetters: '@',
            minNumbers: '@'
          },
          template: '<div class="validationContainer">\
                      <div ng-transclude></div>\
                      <div class="input-help">\
                        <h4>{{fieldErrorDisplay}}</h4>\
                        <ul>\
                          <li data-ng-repeat="rule in requirementSpec" ng-class="rule.class">\
                              {{rule.msg}}\
                          </li>\
                        </ul>\
                      </div>\
                    </div>',
         replace: true,
         link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
                 var validator = function(viewValue){
                          if(scope.valueRequired && viewValue.length == 0 && (!scope.maxLength && !scope.minLength && !scope.minLetters && !scope.minNumbers)){
                    scope.valid = false;  
                    scope.fieldErrorDisplay = scope.fieldName + ' is required';
                  }
                  else{
                        scope.fieldErrorDisplay = scope.fieldName + ' must meet the following requirements: ';
                        scope.requirementSpec = [];
                        if(scope.minLength){
                          var itemValidity = viewValue.length >= scope.minLength;
                          scope.valid = !itemValidity ? false : scope.valid;
                          var item = {
                            'msg' : 'Must be at least ' + scope.minLength + ' characters long',
                            'class' : itemValidity ? 'valid' : undefined
                          };
                          scope.requirementSpec[nameStr].push(item);
                        }
                        else if(scope.valueRequired){
                          var itemValidity = viewValue && viewValue.length >= 1;
                          scope.valid = !itemValidity ? false : scope.valid;
                          var item = {
                            'msg' : 'This field must be filled',
                            'class' : itemValidity ? 'valid' : undefined
                          };
                          scope.requirementSpec[nameStr].push(item);
                        }
                        if(scope.maxLength){
                          var itemValidity = viewValue.length <= scope.maxLength;
                          scope.valid = !itemValidity ? false : scope.valid;
                          var item = {
                            'msg' : 'Must be ' + scope.maxLength + ' characters long at most  ',
                            'class' : itemValidity ? 'valid' : undefined
                          };
                          scope.requirementSpec[nameStr].push(item);
                        }
                        if(scope.minLetters){
                          var itemValidity = (viewValue && /[A-z]/.test(viewValue));
                          scope.valid = !itemValidity ? false : scope.valid;
                          var item = {
                            'msg' : 'Must contain at least ' + scope.minLetters + ' letters',
                            'class' : itemValidity ? 'valid' : undefined
                          };
                          scope.requirementSpec[nameStr].push(item);
                        }
                        if(attrs.minNumbers){
                          var itemValidity = (viewValue && /\d/.test(viewValue));
                          scope.valid = !itemValidity ? false : scope.valid;
                          var item = {
                            'msg' : 'Must contain at least' + attrs.minNumbers + ' numbers',
                            'class' : itemValidity ? 'valid' : undefined
                          };
                          scope.requirementSpec[nameStr].push(item);
                        }
                  }

                  if(scope.valid) {
                      ctrl.$setValidity(nameStr, true);
                      return viewValue;
                  } else {
                      ctrl.$setValidity(nameStr, false);                    
                      return undefined;
                  }
             }

             scope.requirementSpec = {};

             ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
               return validator(viewValue);
             });
             ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function(viewValue) {
               // var before = scope.$eval(attrs.validateBefore);
               if(viewValue && viewValue != "" && viewValue.length > 0)
                 return validator(viewValue);

             });


        });
    }
});
```

Comment: can you post HTML template you used, will be great to see your problem in Fiddle/Plunker. Thanks

Comment: Added plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/vFB9ih6x2NBmwhAes3Qh?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

The solution:
$transclude only takes the compiled content of the element, thus not the element it self.

Obviously I lack the understanding of this significant detail in my implementation.